# Добавить изображение в TImage

Tags: c++, c++builder

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

По многим гайдам в свойствах должно появиться **Picture**, но здесь его нет. Тогда каким образом я могу добавить изображение в этот виджет?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по наличию `MultiResBitmap`, проект относится к FMX, а не к VCL (где свойство `Picture` есть).

В FMX же для отображения картинки можно использовать `TImage` или `TImageControl`, назначая свойство `Bitmap`